# How to disable stack protector for ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to set an environment about stack exploit on ARM.Use ndk-build to compile the source code into binary has a problem, a stack protector within the binary prevent stack from smashing.Is there any way can disable the stack protector for ndk-build?Just like below:

```
gcc overflow.c -o overflow -fno-stack-protector
```

My Android.mk shows below:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Any help will be appreciate.Thank you.

Comment: Are you using gradle to build? Can show your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fno-stack-protector
```